# marcar en negrita o mayúscula un string en un joptionpane

Tags: java

la pregunta es si hay alguna posibilidad de marcar en un string en negrita, mayúscula o alguna forma de resaltarlo

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, nombreP1 + " ,es su turno, con la ficha \"1\" ");
```

la idea es resaltar el contenido de la variable nombreP1 y en numero 
"1"
desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Acuerdo a [esta pregunta en Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008100/formatting-text-in-jdialog-box), al parecer, puedes usar HTML para lograr mostrar texto con algun formato

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para resaltar el texto en "negritas", puedes usar un `JLabel` y el código para bold (`<b>` y `</b>`) de html.

Puedes realizarlo directamente pero en ocasiones esto no es soportado por lo tanto lo mejor es usar un `JLabel`:

```
String texto = "<html><b>Jorgesys</b> ,es su turno, con la ficha <b>1</b></html>";
JLabel label = new JLabel(texto);
label.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 16));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
```

para obtener esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]